# having problem in getting response from the database and i have randomly entered database name as test . used mongodbAtlas for url

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am using mongo Db Atlas to connect to the `MongoDB` database using `mongoose` Don't know why not getting a response on putting `API` on postman it got stuck. here test is the random database name entered here There is no error but on testing, `API` postman gets stuck.

```
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const app = express();
const cors = require('cors')
mongoose.connect('mongodb+srv://shanu:{password}@cluster0.q0rvl.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority', {
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useCreateIndex: true
}).then(() => {
    console.log("connected")
}).catch(err => {
    console.log(err)
});
app.use(express.json)
app.use(cors)
const userroute = require('./Backend/routes/user')
app.use('/users', userroute);
app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log("server running at 32000");
})
const router = require('express').Router();
const User = require('../user.modal');
router.route('/').get((req, res) => {
    User.find()
        .then(users => res.json(users))
        .catch(err => res.status(400).json(err));
});
router.route('/add').post((req, res) => {
    res.send("response recieved");
});
module.exports = router;
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const userschema = new Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    img: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    summary: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    }
});
const User = mongoose.model('User', userschema);
module.exports = User;
```

Comment: it's not good to share your database login information

Comment: thnks for suggestion bro but do you have any solution for this

Comment: add `body-parser`  middleware `app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));` and 
`app.use(bodyParser.json());`

Comment: dont think body-parser must be used in updated version

Comment: What request are you making in Postman and what errors are you getting in return?  A common issue people run into with Atlas is that you must whitelist your IP address in order to access the database.  See https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/security-whitelist/ for more details.

Comment: i am using localhost://3000/users/ and getting nothing as output but it got stuck

Comment: @DivyanshuThakur `json()` is a method use parenthesis and also for `cors()`.